# How to avoid 'Escalation succeeded' when serving my project?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have been working now for 2 weeks on a playbook to deploy CKAN with Ansible on RHEL. I manage to get the site up and running with:

```
- name: test ckan
  shell: ". {{ckan_user.home_path}}/{{ckan_site_name}}/bin/activate && paster serve /etc/ckan/{{ckan_site_name}}/development.ini"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ckan_user.home_path}}/{{ckan_site_name}}/src/ckan"
```

The result is that the playbook is stuck in an infinite loop saying:
'Escalation succeeded'.
I'm sure that there is an easy fix, but I can't find it...

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add “&& exit” or something after your shell command.
Also, register the task, then read it at the next task to see what the output value is.

In this way, you can stop or continue the play based on the output of the task.